# Using babel-polyfill in CRA, cant deploy to heroku

Tags: heroku, create-react-app, babel-polyfill

> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'babel-polyfill' in
>   '/tmp/build_7f85e1e4173bfdceff6d0abd745c2646/src' remote:
>   remote:        error Command failed with exit code 1. remote:
>   info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation
>   about this command. remote:  remote: -----> Build failed remote:
>   remote:        We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot
>   common issues here: remote:
>   https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys

This is the error I get when I try to deploy my app to heroku.

```
"babel-polyfill": "^6.23.0",
```

is in my dependencies (not devDependencies).
I require babel in my index.js file on the first line:

```
import 'babel-polyfill';
```

Why cant heroku resolve the babel-polyfill ?